# I keep getting an EOL Error message on the first line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a diner menu and I don't know what I'm doing wrong on the first line. I think it's an "unexpected indent", but I don't know how to correct it. Any help would be awesome.

```
print("Breakfast_Menu 
    (1) "Pancakes and eggs"
    (2) "Waffles with your pick between apple or oranges"
    (3) "Cheerios with month-old milk"
    (4) "Sausage-Egg Sandwich with yogurt"
    (5) "Sausage Biscuit with bacon"
    (6) "Oatmeal and applesauce"
    (7) "Coffee with air")
```

Comment: The quotes are confusing the `print` statement. Try putting single quotes on either end of the print statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect:

```
print("Breakfast menu
```

opens a string,

```
    (1) "
```

is still part of it, the last `"` closing it.

```
Pancakes and eggs
```

is then parsed as Python code (ie. a variable named `Pancakes`, `and` keyword and another `egg` variable, etc.

The reason you get "EOF" message is that there's **odd** number of double quotes in total.  The last part of your code is actually **opening** a string:

```
")
```

which is never closed.  In other words, *python* gets to the end of file before even parsing the code.

One way of getting what I think you want is:

```
menu = [
    "Pancakes and eggs",
    "Waffles with your pick between apple or oranges",
    "Cheerios with month-old milk",
    "Sausage-Egg Sandwich with yogurt",
    "Sausage Biscuit with bacon",
    "Oatmeal and applesauce",
    "Coffee with air",
]
print("Breakfast menu")
for n, item in enumerate(menu):
    print("(%s) %s" % (n + 1, item))
```

Answer (score 1):

> String literals can span multiple lines. One way is using
>   triple-quotes: """...""" or '''...'''. End of lines are automatically
>   included in the string, but it’s possible to prevent this by adding a
>   \ at the end of the line. The following example:
>
> ```
> print("""\
> Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]
>      -h                        Display this usage message
>      -H hostname               Hostname to connect to
> """)
> ```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) for more information

```
print('''"Breakfast_Menu"
    (1) "Pancakes and eggs"
    (2) "Waffles with your pick between apple or oranges"
    (3) "Cheerios with month-old milk"
    (4) "Sausage-Egg Sandwich with yogurt"
    (5) "Sausage Biscuit with bacon"
    (6) "Oatmeal and applesauce"
    (7) "Coffee with air"''')
```

This will solve it

Comment: adding a brief explanation in addition to the code would make this answer better.